# If I use a vaadin add-on does everyone else on the project need it too?

Tags: vaadin, add-on

I want to use Vaadin's numberField add-on, but I'm working on a project with about two dozen people. If I use this does that mean that all the other developers will have to install it for the code to work for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Vaadin7 you usually have a build script (like maven pom.xml) which handles the dependencies for you.

In that pom.xml you specify all required libraries, just the same way as you specify other java libraries.

If you use maven to build your project, it will automagically resolve all dependencies and download all required addons.

Comment: So is that a yes or a no?

Comment: When using maven, then maven will download the addon(s) for you or your collegues